# Why is this xml file throwing "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" error

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

hello everyone I created a spring MVC project from "https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-multiple-view-page-example" when I just copy-pasted the code it worked fine but when I tried creating the same project by typing instead of copy-pasting the code it showed the exception in the project

> "SEVERE: Servlet [spring] in web application [/multipleviewpage] threw load() exception
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"

the code of the spring-servlet file is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">  
  
    <!-- Provide support for component scanning -->  
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint" ></context:component-scan>  
  
    <!--Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation -->  
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
<!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->  
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>          
     </bean>  
</beans>
```

the web.xml file is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://JAVA.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>  
   <servlet>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>      
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>    
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>
```

also, the HelloController.java file is

```
package com.javatpoint; 

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  

@Controller  
public class HelloController 
{  
    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public String redirect()  
        {  
            return "viewpage";  
        }     
    @RequestMapping("/helloagain")  
    public String display()  
        {  
            return "final";  
        }  
}
```

Comment: By just dding these files and typing them doesn't mean you atuomagically get the dependencies that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your pom.xml file, and could be missing servlet dependency.

```
<dependency>    
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>    
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>    
    <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>    
</dependency>
```